# Android MySQL : Storing image in a database

Tags: php, android, mysql

I really need your opinions. What could be the reason why I cannot make this working. And Android studio is just only giving me this LOG

```
E/ApplicationFormActivity: Submission Error: null
D/Volley: [2] Request.finish: 9692 ms: [ ] https://cremliccamfinpage.000webhostapp.com//eLoanApplication/submit_client.php 0xbc1c7874 NORMAL 1
```

Here is the PHP Script

```html
<iframe src="https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/C7j1ziyU" style="border:none;width:100%"></iframe>
```

and this is the **ApplicationFormActivity**

```html
<iframe src="https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/EJAD3UFM" style="border:none;width:100%"></iframe>
```

Comment: Where is your code? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: can't you see the snippets?